# Creating a custom views filter handler with a non-sql query

Tags: views, location

So, I'm working on a custom views handler that will allow users to filter based on field comparisons.

I've overridden the operator to use my own function defined elsewhere in the module that implements hook_options() that is also used in rules.  I'm trying to guess at an appropriate way of building the query.

The example provided in the default compare_fields class that I'm extending does this:

```
  $snippet = $left_table_alias . '.' . $left_handler->real_field . ' ' . $this->options['operator'] . ' ' . $right_table_alias . '.' . $right_handler->real_field;

  $this->query->add_where_expression($this->options['group'], $snippet);
```

But I'd prefer to use a function I've already defined elsewhere that, instead of using a WHERE clause, will compare two fields with an operator to determine whether a TRUE value is returned from a geophp GEOS method.  The function is as simple as this:

```
function geofield_rules_compare_geofields($left_geometry, $op, $right_geometry) {
$geophp = geophp_load();
$source_wkt = geoPHP::load($left_geometry['geom']);
  if (!$geophp) {
    drupal_set_message(t("Unable to load geoPHP library. Not all values will be calculated correctly"), 'error');
    return;
  }
  if (geoPHP::geosInstalled()) {
      switch ($op) {
      default:
      case 'contains()':
        if ($source_wkt->contains($right_geometry)){
          return true;
        }
      case 'within()':
        if ($source_wkt->within($right_geometry)) {
          return true;
        }
    }
  } else {
    dpm('shit, no GEOS');
  }

  // TODO: More methods
}
```

The operators used in the case statements are provided by the function I already mentioned.

How would *you* go about implementing the views handler filter query in this case?